# DateTme неправильно переводит время между часовыми поясами

Tags: время, php, дата

Нужно получить текущее время по мск.

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Получаю время на час меньше. Работаю на Денвере.

Comment: пользователи *nix эту пляску почти не заметили, я например заметил недавно, когда выяснилось что у одной нашей девочки js неправильно таймзону определяет из-за чего поплыл на час таймер countdown. (я кстати как-то странно себе представляю как пользователи винды вообще живут, если у них gmt поплыл)

Comment: @eicto у нас на работе синхронизация с сервером еще идет (физически к нему не имеем доступа, а админу не до этого), раньше постоянно наше время отгонял на 1 час назад. Решили проблему переходом на другой часовой пояс в настройках.

Comment: @IVsevolod так таймсервер разве не в UTC время отдает ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обновите локали в винде, как-то так http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2863058 а ну ещё и у самого php есть таймзоны - обновите php. Спасибо  за это можете направить в кремль :)

Comment: ну ппц, и тут дотянулись

Answer (score -2):

Можете воспользоваться **date()**:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+1 hour"));
echo $date;
```

**date()** отображает системную дату сервера. Если надо, можете подкорректировать ее с помощью **strtotime()**

Comment: ага а потом в продакшене, где время правильное или часовой пояс не из бСССР у него +1 час... низя так делать, сверхвредный совет!

Comment: костыльчик )))

Comment: на протез больше похоже, причем ампутировали из-за того что порезались и крови испугались.